# Prevent user creation on social login

Tags: social-connected

Ours is a multisite instance running on sc8.0 update 5.
A user record is auto created when visitor logs in using the Social connector, and I need to prevent that for a particular site.

This is what I did.

**custom.config:**

```
<sitecore>
 <pipelines>
  <httpRequestBegin>
   <processor patch:instead="processor[@type='Sitecore.Social.Connector.Pipelines.MatchUser.CreateUser, Sitecore.Social']"
              type="MySite.Foundation.Common.Utilities.SitecoreExtensions+MySiteSocial, MySite.Foundation.Common">
     <sites hint="list">
      <site>MYSITE</site>            
     </sites>
   </processor>
  </httpRequestBegin>
 </pipelines>
</sitecore>
```

**SitecoreExtensions.cs**

```
public class SitecoreExtensions
{
  public class MysiteSocial : HttpRequestProcessor
  {
    public List<string> Sites { get; set; }

    public MysiteSocial()
    {
      Sites = new List<string>();
    }

    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
      if (Sites.Contains(Sitecore.Context.Site.Name))
        return;      
    }
  }
}
```

The user is still getting created. How can I go about achieving what I need.

Comment: you might have to override the Createuser pipeline , to disable user creation on FB login
<social.matchUser>
       ...
        <processor type="Sitecore.Social.Connector.Pipelines.MatchUser.CreateUser, Sitecore.Social" />
      </social.matchUser>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your configuration is targeting the wrong pipeline, by default the Social CreateUser method is in the `social.matchUser` pipeline but your config specifies `httpRequestBegin`.

I would also suggest patching a new processor first and then aborting the pipeline if it meets your criteria:

```cs
public class SitecoreExtensions
{
    public class MySiteSocial
    {
        public List<string> Sites { get; set; }

        public MysiteSocial()
        {
            Sites = new List<string>();
        }

        public void Process(SelectUserPipelineArgs args)
        {
            if (Sites.Contains(Sitecore.Context.Site.Name))
                args.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

And the associated config patch to add this as the first processor in the correct pipeline:

```
<sitecore>
 <pipelines>
  <social.matchUser>
   <processor type="MySite.Foundation.Common.Utilities.SitecoreExtensions.MySiteSocial, MySite.Foundation.Common" patch:before="*[1]">
     <sites hint="list">
      <site>MYSITE</site>            
     </sites>
   </processor>
  </social.matchUser>
 </pipelines>
</sitecore>
```